# OpenStack can't install nova-compute

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

Trying to setup an openstack instance on my servers running **Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS** following the OpenStack installation guide. Now I'm trying to install `nova-compute` on my compute node, but I run into the following error:

```
sudo apt install nova-compute
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Einige Pakete konnten nicht installiert werden. Das kann bedeuten, dass
Sie eine unmögliche Situation angefordert haben oder, wenn Sie die
Unstable-Distribution verwenden, dass einige erforderliche Pakete noch
nicht erstellt wurden oder Incoming noch nicht verlassen haben.
Die folgenden Informationen helfen Ihnen vielleicht, die Situation zu lösen:

Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 nova-compute : Hängt ab von: nova-compute-kvm soll aber nicht installiert werden oder
                               nova-compute-hypervisor
                Hängt ab von: python3-nova (= 2:22.1.0-0ubuntu1~cloud0) soll aber nicht installiert werden
E: Probleme können nicht korrigiert werden, Sie haben zurückgehaltene defekte Pakete.
```

I seems that some dependencies are not installed on my machine yet, assume that all required repositories have been added to it.

Any suggests were this error could come from?

Comment: What happens when you try to install `nova-compute-kvm`? I have the feeling that your Ubuntu installation contains libraries that are incompatible with Nova. I would use a fresh installation before installing OpenStack.

Comment: Installation was fresh. Problem was a missing repository `Universe` on the compute node. After adding this one, installation was asuccessful. Thanks.